# Integrate 2 standalone projects developed in windows form

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a standalone hotel management project and a stand alone restaurant project in windows form.
now i want to integrate both projects. and restaurant act as a room service in hotel 
please help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `and restaurant act as a room service in hotel please` - Did not get much on this one ??

Answer (score 1):

Like a fast and dirty solution:

- compile your Restorant project like `dll`
- ensure that it exposes all necessary types for Hotel project interaction
- add that `dll` to a Hotel project

Answer (score 0):

You can add one project to another by using visual studio --> add project in solution explorer. And make sure that namespace of both project will be same so that both will be integrated.

In **solution Explorer--> Right click and click on Add --> Existing project--> locate your project and add.**

Make name  namespace of both project as same.

Try it..

Comment: no thanks i do it by myself 
its my bad to ask this question here